# C - passing elements from within structures to functions

Tags: c, pointers, structure

I have a structure comprised of an array of pointers to other structures of a different type.

```
    typedef struct{
        NodeT* nodes[2];
        int size; 
    }stackT;
```

with:

```
    typedef struct{
        char info; 
    }NodeT;
```

And I have a pointer to the above (first) structure:

```
    stackT* stackPtr;
```

Assuming the memory is allocated for the stackT structure as well as both NodeT structures with associated assignments for the members of both NodeT structures, how would I pass to a function one of the pointers in stackT?

---

For example:

```
    void setChar(NodeT* nodePtr, char setTo){
        nodePtr->info = setTo;
    }
```

called with line:

```
    setChar(stackPtr->nodes[0], 'A');
```

Does not work. I figured it had something to do with the -> syntax dereferencing the pointer whereby I am actually passing in a structure. I do not get any compilation errors, but when I check for the assignment by printing whatever is stored in `char info` I do not get anything.

Is the notation incorrect or do I have issues elsewhere in the program perhaps? I just wanted to rule this out first (proper passing syntax).

Comment: At first glance it looks ok to me.

Comment: One way to do this is using <del>de</del>reference operator:
`&stackPtr->nodes[0]`.

Another way - plain pointer math:
`stackPtr->nodes + 0`

Comment: What error are you getting and which compiler you use?

Comment: Is the first proper or should it be `&(stackPtr->nodes[0])` ?

Comment: @Mauren, I actually do not get any compilation errors. I am using GCC anyway. I just wanted to first make sure that I was using proper syntax before continuing.

Comment: How are you printing out char info?

Comment: It works well without any brackets. But... to be safe and sure... :)

Comment: @CharlieBurns, well that ties back into the problem of passing pointers in this manner. Assuming the above syntax is correct the call would be -> `printf("Char is: %c", stack->nodes[0]->info)`.

Comment: @Kamiccolo, So the syntax `stackPtr->nodes[0]` returns a pointer and not a structure? That is what I was assuming in the above post, but I was concerned the -> operator was actually dereferencing whatever `stackPtr.nodes[0]` is.

Comment: @sherrellbc, that printf looks fine. Maybe we need to see more code.

Comment: @sherrellbc, it returns pointer to a structure :)

You can access structures just by pointer.

Comment: Did you use dynamic memory allocation?

Comment: @Mauren, yes the structures are dynamically allocated with calls to malloc().

Comment: Can't understand why this doesn't work. I just tested here with both static and dynamic allocation and the char field was correctly set.

Comment: @Mauren, well thanks for the input then. Perhaps I have some other problems with my code. The only thing I wanted to accomplish with this question was to verify the syntax I was using to pass the pointers.

Comment: From the code posted above it's impossible to tell where is the error. Could you provide some extra code lines?

Comment: @Maruren, perhaps my problem is in the way I allocate the memory. I use the line `stackT* stackPtr = malloc(sizeof(stackPtr));` Is this correct?

Comment: That is incorrect you need to use something like `stackT *stackPtr = malloc(sizeof(stackT));`  or `stackT *stackPtr = malloc(sizeof(*stackPtr));`

Comment: I've always used the syntax sizeof(stackT), for example, and it works fine. Intuitively, the syntax does not make sense but I guess it's all worked out inside the compiler. The problem I was having when I posted this question has been resolved.

Comment: @sherrellbc could you provide your own answer to the question? Maybe someone is looking for such a solution too.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for a solution to this problem, the above code was actually correct.
Assuming you have an array of pointer in some structure and you wish to pass such a pointer, the correct syntax would be:

```
someFunc( structPtr->ptrArray[0] )
```

The line:

```
structPtr->ptrArray[0]
```

Actually returns a pointer, and not whatever the pointer is pointer to.

```
(*structPtr).ptrArray[0]
```

Is also equivalent.

That being said, I either mistakenly interpreted the information before me, or I had underlying errors elsewhere in the my code.